# simple android video player

Tags: android, listview, dynamic, android-videoview

i'm very very new to android/java and am trying to create a basic video player on android.
i have researched all throughout stackoverflow, google, youtube, etc but i really can't seem to find a way to do this..

my goal is to have a listview that shows all the compatible videos on the android device. then, after tapping on one of the items in the listview, the video would play.

i did find some very helpful resources, such as http://www.android-trainer.com/playing-with-videos-from-content-providers-part-3-.html , but this code uses the deprecated method managedquery()

i was then lead to this website: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_loading-data_cursorloader/comment-page-1/#comment-15832 to find a way around the managedquery() method, but judging from the comments, this tutorial is ridden with bugs... i tried to debug the tutorial but i was hoping someone could give me a clear explanation of what to do...

should i focus on the first link and figure out how to go around the deprecated managedquery() method? if so, how do i go about avoiding the managedquery() method?

or is there another, perhaps simpler, way of creating a video player that can play all the videos in the device?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you want the list to come from? Are you ok with using the default video player?
Where are the videos stored?

ManagedQuery (and cursorloader) is for traversing through a database. You don't need that.

Comment: thank you for responding so quickly! i think there's multiple approaches-
1. default video player: i'm okay with this, but will this be usable for different types of devices? for instance, if i call one device's default player, is it the same as another device?
2. database: i think i could also create a database to store the videos, but i'm not sure if that's necessary...can't i just access the device's videos (external and internal storage) with MediaStore.Videos.etc?

Comment: 1. No. In my experience, devices' default players have different behaviors - more of a problem with lower version, but if you want consistency, it's really easy to make your own player.

2. Where is the data coming from? you don't want overhead of parsing from a text file and writing it to db, just to read from db. It would make sense though if it's from an http response. If you're planning to use the default videos folder you can use Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES). More info here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html

Comment: ideally, i'd like the data to come from anywhere- sdcard, default videos, and maybe even streaming online Youtube videos (but i'm assuming that's an entirely separate task itself). i've been able to get the video player working with a test video i put into the raw folder, and i guess i could just manually put all the videos i want to be played in that folder, but it would be nice if the player can play every file on the device that ends with .3gp and .mp4. is this doable? can i implement getExternalStorageDirectory() for both internal and external storage at the same time?

Comment: nevermind i got it! i used, as you had advised, the getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(). i also used the getExternalStorageDirectory, though i'm not sure if that was particularly beneficial in any way. thank you for steering me in the right direction!